# Is SG-10's appearance in "SG-1: A Matter of Time" their first mission?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, continuity

In *SG-1*'s second season episode *A Matter of Time,* SG-10 is described as being on its first mission, with Major Boyd [in charge](https://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s2/216.shtml).

> SG-10, a new field unit commanded by Major Henry Boyd and on its first mission, is in trouble. The three men and one woman rush, seemingly in slow motion, toward the Stargate on another world, and begin dialing home to Earth.

But SG-10 is mentioned as being created much earlier in the first season episode [*In the Line of Duty*](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/SG-10).

Is that just the usual kind of continuity error that is common with most TV shows or could this have been Major Boyd's first command of the unit? Alternatively, could the team have been in training this entire time? Could time travel detailed in a later episode or book explain it? Is there any evidence to support any of these escape clauses?

Comment: I suspect SG teams other than SG-1 get [completely wiped out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/435Rg.png) at an alarming rate.

Comment: Alternatively, they probably go through a ton of training as a team before a first mission.

Comment: @Paul - A good point, but then wouldn't their first mission have been a baby mission, in tandem with another team?

Comment: Is it a continuity error or is it time-travel retcon?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - I hadn't thought of that alternative. Their time travel episodes were some of my favorites. They were often played with a sense of humor that I enjoyed. But offhand, I can't think of one that would have fixed this particular continuity error. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: No. While a fan of the show, I value my sanity too much to try to keep a mental map of the chronology. I was more making a generalised statement about SG:1's predilection for such things.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - Got it. And it's a good point. You can sweep a lot of problems under the tent's carpet with a little judicious time travel—and create some interesting new ones.

Comment: @Paul - I added your suggestion about a training period as a reasonable escape clause into the question. Thanks!

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - and I added time travel to the question as a possible escape clause. Appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [episode script](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.15_%22A_Matter_Of_Time%22_Transcript) indicates that this was their first episode ***as a team***

> **O'NEILL:** *Henry Boyd. Good officer. Smart. Kinda reminds me of Carter a little. This was their first mission as a team.*

Hammond indicates that SG-10 was created a few months earlier in '[In the Line of Duty](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/2.02_%22In_The_Line_Of_Duty%22_Transcript)'

> **HAMMOND:** *Agreed. But relocation is the first priority. I'm assigning the three new SG teams 10 through 12 to coordinate with you.
>   Dismissed.*

That being the case, the strong indication is that **whilst the Unit ID was in use, there was a different team using it.** Given that the average lifespan of a (non SG-1) SG team member is approximately that of an injured mayfly, it's hardly surprising that they needed to replace them.

Comment: Does that make the stargate a kind of man-sized bug zapper?

Comment: @rosesunhill - SG-1 are so resilient that they've **each died at least once**. By comparison, Boyd gets killed on his first trip.